# How to convert Hourly data to daily average for two variables?

Tags: r, vector, air, average

I am working on observing PM 10 data on a daily average for 3 years. I have already worked on my air quality data however, my temperature and wind speed data are hourly. How can I calculate the daily average and combine both of these data?

Eg:

| date | temperature | Wind_Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/01/2018 1:00 | 18.8 | 1.9 |
| 1/01/2018 2:00 | 18.7 | 1.5 |
| 1/01/2018 3:00 | 18.6 | 1.6 |
| 1/01/2018 4:00 | 18.5 1.0 |  |
| 1/01/2018 5:00 | 18.1 | 1.2 |

... all the way until 1/1/2021 00:00 (26304 obs).

I tried

```
StartDateTime = dmy_hm("-01-01-2018 01:00")
EndDateTime <- dmy_hm("01-01-2021 00:00")
DF <- data.frame(DateTime = c(seq.POSIXt(StartDateTime, EndDateTime, by = "hour"),
                              seq.POSIXt(StartDateTime, EndDateTime, by = "hour")),
                 check.rows = TRUE, fix.empty.names = TRUE, 
              )
head(DF)
```

- It changed the DF into one variable and 52608 obs. I am super lost at this stage.

My pm10 data has is a time series [1:1096]- atomic vector. Any suggestions on how I can change the hourly data into daily average for both temperature and wind speed so I can combine it with the pm10 data?

data: dput(head(sample_data_1))

Comment: Can you include a sample of your original data in the form you have it? e.g. `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` will make a code recipe you can put into your question so we can load it the same way you have it.

Comment: In abstract, I would add a variable to record the date (as opposed to your datetime), then use `dplyr` code like `df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarize(across(2:3, mean))`. That would give the daily average for each of the variables in position 2 and 3.

Comment: Hi, I tried to add the data, I cannot seem to add the data here

Comment: What I meant was "please run the code `dput(head(sample_data_1))` in your R console. That will produce a bunch of code that you can paste into your question. When we run that code we can produce an exact copy of the first few rows of your data frame."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your data looks like `DF2` (and you use `lubridate`)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
StartDateTime <- dmy_hm("-01-01-2018 01:00")
EndDateTime <- dmy_hm("01-01-2021 00:00")
date_hour_seq <- seq.POSIXt(StartDateTime, EndDateTime, by = "hour")
DF2 <- data.frame(DateTime = date_hour_seq,
                  temperatur = rnorm(length(date_hour_seq), 10),
                  wind = rnorm(length(date_hour_seq), 1, .1))
```

Then you can create a new `date` variable in `group_by` and
calculate the average using `summarise`:

```r
DF2 %>% group_by(date = date(DateTime)) %>%
  summarise(temperatur = mean(temperatur), 
            wind = mean(wind))
#> # A tibble: 1,097 × 3
#>    date       temperatur  wind
#>    <date>          <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2018-01-01       9.98 1.03 
#>  2 2018-01-02       9.85 1.00 
#>  3 2018-01-03       9.88 1.02 
#>  4 2018-01-04      10.3  1.02 
#>  5 2018-01-05       9.83 0.979
#>  6 2018-01-06      10.1  1.00 
#>  7 2018-01-07       9.74 0.984
#>  8 2018-01-08       9.96 0.997
#>  9 2018-01-09      10.3  1.01 
#> 10 2018-01-10      10.1  0.987
#> # … with 1,087 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That worked. I am able to see the mean values however, I cannot change the DF2 into new table? Would it be possible to create a new data ofd the mean values only?

Comment: `DF3 <- DF2 %>% group_by(date = date(DateTime)) %>% summarise(temperatur = mean(temperatur), wind = mean(wind))`